# Why do we add "javascript:" before calling a function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

if I change  `<button onclick="javascript:myFunction()">Click me</button>` by

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

my code runs normally.

Is that a difference between `onclick="javascript:myFunction()"` and `onclick="myFunction()"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol, that has got lost. It's used when you have Javascript in an URL, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi')">Hi</a>
```

An event attribute doesn't support the `:javascript` protocol, so it doesn't work there. However, it happens to become the same syntax as a label in Javascript, so the code actually still works eventhough the protocol is in the wrong place.

So, in conclusion, the `:javascript` shouldn't be there, and it's just plain luck that it still happens to work when it is.